# Coloured Terminal Text for a mitmdump in-line Python script without additional modules

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I have a in-line python script for mitmdump I would like to output coloured text to a terminal window.

I need it to work on all three platforms (Mac, Linux and Windows 7, 8 and 10) and importantly not require the installation of python, python modules or any other third party tool.

ANSI escape codes obviously would be the solution were it not for the fact that Windows 7 and 8 do not support them.

Since mitmproxy for Windows works without needing to install any form of python, and also prints coloured text to the terminal itself, there has to be a way, I just do not know what it is.

I have searched for an answer and not found a solution, my apologies if I missed one.

Comment: if `mitmproxy` uses colors then check in its [source code](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy) - it is in Python.

Comment: I looked in source code and found it imports [urwid](http://urwid.org/)

Comment: import urwid causes a script error :( No module named urwid

Comment: if you use `mitmproxy` without installing then you shouldn't have access to `urwid`.

Comment: if you install `mitmproxy` using `pip` then you can do `import mitmproxy` and `import urwid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the fantastic [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/) library internally. If you work with master (soon-to-be-3.0), check out https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/mitmproxy/addons/termlog.py or https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/mitmproxy/addons/dumper.py.